# Meaning of equations involving modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Does the following congruence equations have any meaning? If yes then please elaborate on what is it in a simplified form?

For integers a,b,c,p,m,n...

a ≡ b mod(m) mod(n)

p ≡ c^(mod(a))

p ≡ c^(mod(a)) mod(b)

Comment: You can make sense out of the first one, though it isn't great.  you can take the remainder on division of $b \pmod m$, and then take the remainder of that on division by $n$.  The other two don't mean anything that I can imagine.

Comment: at least now without further variables.

Comment: For the 2nd one..... Can't we define it as 'a' divides (log p base c - 1)?

Comment: only dicrete logs matter in mod.

Answer (score 1):

The second and third equations make no sense. The first would make sense in form: $$a\equiv ((b \mod m) \mod n)$$

Comment: first *  is the proper spelling.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee: sorry my error, corrected.